# Deploy from Travis to Cloud Foundry

Tags: travis-ci, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I'm trying to deploy an app from Travis to Cloud Foundry.

My .travis.yml looks like this:

```
deploy:
  provider: cloudfoundry
  api: https://api.run.pivotal.io
  username:
    secure: "... secure username, generated with travis cli"
  password:
    secure: "... secure password, generated with travis cli"
  organization: my-org
  space: development
  on:
    repo: username/repository
    branch: master
```

Organization, space, repository, encrypted username and password are double checked and are correct.

Yet, travis log tells me:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
Preparing deploy
cf
Setting api endpoint to https://api.run.pivotal.io...
OK

API endpoint:   https://api.run.pivotal.io (API version: 2.37.0)   
Not logged in. Use 'cf login' to log in.
API endpoint: https://api.run.pivotal.io
Authenticating...
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

Logging in manually works like a charm. 
**Anyone an idea what the problem could be?**

I'm not sure whether it's me, travis or cloud foundry (PWS) that cocks up.

Comment: Have you checked out these docs: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/cloudfoundry/.  Looks like you might need to add `edge: true`, and also perhaps not encrypt your username?

Comment: Yes. I have tried with and without edge: true - with no luck. I have also tried plain/encrypted username - neither worked.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and discovered that I had special characters in my password. If you have them, at the command line you need to enclose your password in quotes and escape the special characters.

Comment: you made my day! that is it! please add an official answer, and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and discovered that I had special characters in my password.

If your password contains special characters, then when calling **travis encrypt** at the command line you need to enclose your password in quotes and escape the special characters.

Details can be seen here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Note-on-escaping-certain-symbols